# How to set boolean value in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

This is the bean,

```
public boolean paid;
public boolean isPaid()
{
    return paid;
}
public void setPaid(boolean paid)
{
    this.paid=paid;
}
```

But when i create an object to save in database like,

CourseFee fee=new CourseFee(); 
fee.setPaid(false);
hibernateTemplate.save(fee);

I get the following exception,

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data too long for column 'paid' at row 1

Which is the correct way to set boolean values in hibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using big `Boolean` in your POJO class.

Or try updating your mapping like this:

```
<property name="paid" not-null="true" >
   <column sql-type="BOOLEAN" not-null="true" name="paid" />
</property>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I still get the same exception.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a good idea to avoid primitives when dealing with Hibernate.

Comment: Can you just share your mapping for the class.

Comment: i'm using hibernate annotations. So, there is no mapping class.

Comment: and the mysql jar is mysql-connector-java-3.1.6-bin.jar, is this causing the problem?

Comment: Ok. Then these links can help you:http://josian.wordpress.com/tag/hibernate/, http://ukitech.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-tinyint-for-java-boolean-types.html.

Answer (score 12):

I use this way.

```
@Column(name="isAdmin", columnDefinition = "tinyint default false")
public boolean isAdmin() {
   return admin;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I do not succeed in using default value. It compiles but default value is never used.

I followed following steps :

- put on Class declaration

  > @DynamicInsert
  >   @DynamicUpdate
- put on property

  > @Column(
  >     nullable = false,
  >     columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN DEFAULT false" ) )

  or Add boolean option as a bit

> @Column ( precision = 1, scale = 0, nullable = false, columnDefinition 
>   = "bit default 1" )

Reference : http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-insert-attribute-example/