# How to set @Column name dynamically in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, data-modeling

I am trying to set column name dynamically in a class(given below) but in `@Column` it need constant value as name.

```
public class Common
 {
  final String pre_col_name_created;

  public Common( String pre_col_name )
    {
    this.pre_col_name_created = pre_col_name;
    }

  @Column( name = pre_col_name_created + "" )
  private String created;
}
```

above code give me error: [image: Attribute value must be constant]

Please suggest me to give `pre_col_name_created` value dynamically from other class in `@Column`.

I already refer below links:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963817/how-to-set-cookie-name-dynamically-in-rails-controller),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288748/how-can-i-set-model-name-dynamically-in-angular),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645057/hibernate-pass-column-name-dynamically-to-the-query),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280567/how-to-set-the-css-class-name-dynamically-in-lesscss),[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48784612/how-to-set-element-name-dynamically-in-reactjs),[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626341/how-to-set-read-only-columns-in-hibernate),[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405190/how-to-set-column-size-in-hibernate-without-using-annotations),[8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080422/how-to-set-column-names),[9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059529/how-to-access-column-name-dynamically-in-kendo-grid-template),[10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745018/how-to-set-columns-dynamically-in-kendo-template),[11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442555/set-column-name-ddply),[12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327114/how-to-set-column-name-in-datatable),[13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880158/sql-query-pass-column-name-dynamically),[14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073544/set-database-name-dynamically-in-sql-server-stored-procedure),[15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689542/how-to-set-layout-span-layout-margin-dynamically-in-code-in-android),[16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535989/manually-set-column-name-in-rails-model),[17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328613/how-to-set-boolean-value-in-hibernate),[18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411699/generate-column-name-dynamically-in-sql-server),[19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808826/adding-column-name-dynamically-in-alter-table),[20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602010/how-to-set-projection-for-concatenated-result-of-two-columns-in-hibernate-criter),[21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343522/how-to-fetch-json-array-name-dynamically-in-javascript),[22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357915/how-to-pass-table-name-dynamically-in-linq-to-sql),[23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695019/how-to-alter-column-name-in-hibernate-entity)

my goal is: I am creating 10 tables and all tables contain `created` column but prefix with different value that set as per Data model class.

for ex.:
tables `abc` and `qwe`
table `abc` has `id`,`a_column`(varchar) and 
table `qwe` has `id`, `q_column`(varchar)

Using `@Transient` I got error:

[image: transient error]

Comment: I think it is not possible to do so, but, you may to use some VO Class (like sub class) and then map it to entity you need, just a tip

Comment: What is your goal with dynamic tables?

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Stefan please refer edit question.

Comment: Variables in annotations must be constant. There can't be instances of a class with different annotated values. Use, as already mentioned subclasses and override the attributes

Comment: @Lino Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Use an embeddable or sub classes. There is no way to have only one JPA entity that maps to several tables.

Comment: @AKAggarwal The answer is: What you try to do is just impossible, due to the constraints of the language itself. You **have** to create a new class for every table/entity you want to map. You maybe want to have a look at `@MappedSupperclass` and `@AttributeOverrides`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is solution for you:

**Test.java**

```
@Entity
@Filter(
    name = "tenancyFilter",
    condition = "et_created = :created"
)
@AttributeOverride(
    name = "created",
    column = @Column(
        name = "et_created"
    )
)
public class Test extends Common
{
    @Id
    @Column( name = "comp_id" )
    private UUID id;

    public UUID getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( UUID id )
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**Common.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners( { AuditingEntityListener.class})
@FilterDef(
    name = "tenancyFilter",
    parameters = {@ParamDef(
        name = "created",
        type = "timestamp"
    )}
)
public class Common
{

    private Timestamp created;

    public Timestamp getCreated()
    {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated( Timestamp created )
    {
        this.created = created;
    }
}
```

In above code there is Test class which you can use as classes where you want to change name of column and In class Common you can define type of common column you want.

Below is screenshot of Database:
[image: screenshot]

I am waiting for you comment.Thanks

Comment: Thanks Ankit but i am getting error: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: An entity cannot be annotated with both @Entity and @MappedSuperclass: com.postgresspringbootgradle.postgresspringbootgradle.entity.Test`

Comment: @AKAggarwal Please remove `@MappedSuperclass` in from Test Class.Because `@MappedSuperclass` and `@Entity` not work together.

Comment: Thanks for your Help.

Comment: @AKAggarwal your Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you cannot, hibernate mapping will be evaluated when initializing the datasrouce beans  which is in the startup of your application.